# SpriteKit to Springboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, sprite-kit

I have developed my application using SpriteKit. Now I'm thinking about translating into native springboard project in order to improve the performances and use standard item without programming their behavior twice.

Actually I'm checking all of my possibilities before starting with the entire translation (I want to be sure that every graphic statements I have created could be translate successful).

For instance:

[image]

This is a schematic concept about the levels. It provides a list of all levels available divided by world (a sort of scrolling list). Searching for solutions I saw a lot of customization using UITableView and Cells but my question is: Can I get the same result with those elements?

Comment: so by springboard you are referring to UIKit (Springboard is the iOS home screen app).  I am not sure if moving to UIKit will gain you much performance,  from my experience, I have always found UIKit to be slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the same results with UIKit,  you may not want to use UITableView though, not sure how it handles overlapping. You can achieve the results by just applying constraints to all of your sub views though to achieve the desired results